# Accessing Dropbox's "Disable Downloads" option on Zapier

Tags: download, webhooks, dropbox, zapier, disable

I feel a bit like I'm in over my head here but I'm trying to pursue this and maybe come to a solution.

All we really need is the ability to disable downloads on Dropbox from Zapier when we're creating a shared link, something that’s available in the native Dropbox link sharing menu, but an option Zapier has not made available on their Dropbox menus yet at this time. It’s something that I’ve been stuck on and a feature that we need for our business and has caused a great deal of stress in our workflow.

Is there a way to accomplish this with webhooks or something of that sort?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API itself does offer the ability to control the download option on shared links, e.g., during shared link creation using [/2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings) via the `SharedLinkSettings.allow_download` field. Ideally, Zapier would implement support for that option.

Otherwise, you can also programmatically modify existing shared links yourself (say, after they're created in Zapier) using [/2/sharing/modify_shared_link_settings](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-modify_shared_link_settings). (You can lookup/list existing shared links using [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links).)